# Need help understanding an indesign feature

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography

I’ve been stumped on what exactly the practical use for the "first baseline offset" option could be used for under text frame options?

I understand that it shifts around the first baseline in that frame but i struggle with, what is the point of doing that if you could just align all the lines to a grid using a common leading?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes helpful when you are working with different fonts or different paragraph/character styles in different Text Frames, and, of course, if you are using extensively and actively the baseline grid (e.g. using the baseline alignment for all/for the majority of your texts). In the same palette you can also set up a different baseline distance, which will only apply to that frame and that can become pretty useful.

It becomes also handy if you have tricky fonts that may have been badly designed or that look odd because of their conformation in respect of the Text Frame box.

Comment: Its also useful if you want to make custom fractions, typeset math, having text on path, and want the path to be visible but text not exactly on path but offset ...

Comment: Yes, that kind of adjustments :)